# WSO2 ESB pass through proxy for .NET web service with windows authentication

Tags: .net, wso2, windows-authentication, esb, wso2-esb

I have WSO2 ESB 4.0.3. I am trying to create a pass through proxy for a .Net web service that has windows authentication enabled. I am getting an error

> "Error trying to add the proxy service to the ESB configuration :
>   TESTPROXY :: Error reading from wsdl URI".

The wsdl URL works fine in the browser though. I am able to create the pass through proxy for this web service successfully if I enable anonymous authentication, but I do not want to do that though.

How can I create a pass through proxy for a .Net web service with windows authentication enabled? Any information that would help me figure out the solution would be appreciated. Thanks.